# Why questions like "Developer laptop SSD and HDD setup" are closed?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

I want to ask why this question is closed:

[Where to put Visual Studio and SQL Server databases - SSD or HDD?](https://superuser.com/questions/425415/developer-laptop-ssd-and-hdd-setup)

I would like to discuss about topic like this and share my experience related with using SSD+HDD configuration with databases, programming, servers etc. It is very constructive for me!

I guess that programmers are small part of this community and there are a lot of people who don't care about them...

Come on guys, is this site for "super users" or just "computer repair mans"?

Comment: _discuss about topic like this_ [su] is a Q&A site, not a discussion board. ALso, the close reason mentions why it's closed.

Comment: No need to edit your question asking if it's better now after the edits. We can all clearly see the "edited" message on the question that tells us when and by whom the question was edited. If you really felt the need to point out this information to us, you could add it in a comment. I rolled back your revision to demonstrate that this is not necessary, and only serves to clutter up your question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let's go through the original question, one bit at a time:

> Lenovo Thinkpad W520 - Add 128GB or 256GB Vertex 4

It's nice that he was specific enough to list his exact hardware, but it seems that we would unable to offer him any meaningful advice in the *general* sense of having an SSD. For example, your storage strategy on a 64 GB SSD would be very different from your strategy with a 1 TB SSD. In two years when 2 TB SSDs are common, use cases will be even more different. This suggests that this question will get old and stale over time.

> I am going to get an ultra-bay for the current HDD for mass storage and data overflow. I am looking at the best way to setup the OS and applications. Going to run Windows 7, Visual Studio, Sql Server Express, and Expressions among other smaller less intensive apps.

...So this question would only help people who are running roughly the same workload as this person. Sounds very localized.

> 1) General rule of thumb, what should be on the HDD to save space on the SSD?

This seems kind of a common sense thing to me. For one thing, **bytes are bytes** -- if you're trying to "save space" on one storage device, move bytes -- **any bytes** -- from that device to another. Obvious question is obvious.

> 2) Should the sql db files (three around 4GB each) be on the HDD or SSD?

Again, this seems like an *absolute no-brainer*. SQL Database files tend to be small and are under very frequent write IOPS. This is **the canonical best-case usage scenario** of an SSD device, especially in a configuration where you have both mechanical and SSD storage. It's like asking if your new car is best driven on roads or oceans.

> 3) Are there any file types that will not matter which drive they're on?

Storage devices do not care at all about "file types". They see every file as a sequence of bytes.

Basically, this is a silly, silly question whose answers are trivial, obvious, not very interesting, and even the ones where some useful advice *may* be possible, are extremely restricted to this guy's particular setup. If you change the program workload or SSD size significantly, the advice could change. The question **could** be generalized so that a general answer could be developed, but the question as it stands is far too localized.

Comment: I believe `allquixotic's` point about how localized it is that although there is no longer a close reason for questions that are too localized they still don't make good questions.

Comment: @Ramhound That's true. (Except in certain cases, when a close reason is removed, it doesn't mean the questions are now on-topic. The custom-comment off-topic close reason exists to cover topics previously covered by boilerplate close reasons. Example: the "bugs in beta software and prototype hardware" close reason was removed, but questions about those are still to be closed.)

Comment: @damryfbfnetsi - I know;  I didn't want to ramble on about it though.  I was just trying to explain that while there isn't a specific "too localized" close reason, localized questions very often, are not good questions to begin with ( which is one of the reasons there was a "too localized" reason at one time ).

Comment: @Ramhound Yeah, the reason they removed it was because it was being abused (only in 50% of cases was it used correctly).

Answer (score 2):

> As it currently stands, this question is not a good fit for our Q&A
>   format. We expect answers to be supported by facts, references, or
>   expertise, but this question will likely solicit debate, arguments,
>   polling, or extended discussion.

Granted, that close reason isn't in use any more

> **Unclear what you're asking**    Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's
>   currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See
>   the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.

May work

or even

> **Primarily opinion-based**  Many good questions generate some degree of
>   opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will
>   tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts,
>   references, or specific expertise.

Would work too.

*Good* questions have definate correct answers. Questions with answers that are *entirely* based on opinion are off topic there.

Comment: "Unclear what you're asking" for me - it is very clear.

Comment: OK. I got it. But instead of just closing - someone could explain that to this new user that he should change his question to more "Q&A" format and ask more clearly.

Comment: @Kamil The whole point of the close reasons is that they give an explanation of what's wrong and how to fix your question. Why should I tell the user again, if the close reason already links to the help page and explains what to do? Also, the user visited the site only to accept the answer, didn't do anything else, and never came back to fix the post.

Comment: @Kamil: There's a reason I 'simply' posted the close reasons as the bulk of my answer. Think of them as "standard" close comments.